# Split zsh array from subshell by linebreak

Tags: shell-script, zsh, array

I would like to instantiate a zsh array from a subshell

```
myarray=($(somecommand)
```

and I check if I received what I wanted with

```
for element in $myarray ; do echo "===" ; echo $element ; echo "---" ; done
```

By default I see that whitespaces (spaces and line breaks) are used to separate elements.

I also found that I can use `${(s:-:)"$(somecommand)"}` to separate by `-`, in which case spaces and line breaks do not break elements (i.e. array elements can contain line breaks).

So far I fail to split at line breaks only. I.e. if `somecommand` returns

```
Alice
Bob
Arthur C Clarke
Neo
Thomas Anderson
```

I want my above `for` loop to print:

```
===
Alice
---
===
Bob
---
===
Arthur C Clarke
---
===
Neo
---
===
Thomas Anderson
---
```

How do I achieve that? (And possibly pointers where to look that up in the manual.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The native splitting operator (beside the Bourne-like `$IFS` word splitting which is done on unquoted command substitutions) is with the `s` parameter expansion flag:

```
array=(${(ps:\n:)"$(cmd)"})
```

would split the output of `cmd` on newline, discarding the empty elements (the empty lines).

`p` is to enable those `\x` expansions. As `ps:\n:` is a common one, it's got a shorter alias: `f` (to split on line **f**eeds):

```
array=(${(f)"$(cmd)"})
```

To preserve the empty lines, you'd do:

```
array=("${(f@)$(cmd)"})
```

Now, beware that like in most other shells, command substitution strips **all** the trailing newline characters, so all trailing empty lines. To preserve those, you can do:

```
array=("${(f@)$(cmd; echo .)}")
array[-1]=()  # remove that last line added by echo .
```

---

With `$IFS` word splitting:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(cmd)) # removes empty lines. Note that contrary to other
               # Bourne-like shells, zsh doesn't do globbing there
               # so you don't need the "set -o noglob"

IFS=$'\n\n' # like in ksh93, doubling an IFS-whitespace character
            # removes its special treatment as a whitespace character
array=($(cmd)) # preserves empty lines except the trailing ones

IFS=$'\n\n'
array=($(cmd; echo .)); array[-1]=() # preserves all empty lines.
```

To avoid modifying `$IFS` globally, you can do the above in an anonymous function:

```
(){
  local IFS=$'\n\n'
  array=($(cmd; echo .)); array[-1]=()
}
```

---

Also beware that the `$array` expansion skips the empty elements. So if you wanted to loop over *all* the elements including the empty ones, you'd need:

```
for i ("$array[@]") ...
```

or

```
for i ("${(@)array}") ...
```

not

```
for i ($array) ...
for i in $array
```